# Can a td be the relatively positioned ancestor of an absolutely positioned element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position

I have an image that I want to transition to another image. It is the only child of a containing `td` element.

So first I style the td with `.css('position', 'relative')`

Then create the second image and give it some properties:

```
var img = $('<image src="a.png" />')
   .css({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: 0,
      left: 0,
      opacity: 0,
      'z-index': 1
   })
   .appendTo($td) ;
```

Finally I animate the old image and the new one:

```
img.fadeIn(1000);
oldimg.fadeOut(1000);
```

At the end of the animation I can remove the old image and reset all the css properties.

Now, this all works great in IE7, but FireFox 5 is sending the replacement image up to the top left of the `div` containing the `table` instead of perfectly overlaying the existing image in the `td`. Is this correct behavior? Is a `td` not a valid relatively positioned ancestor because it's not a block element or something like that?

Suggestions of better ways to make one image fade to another are welcome.

**Update**

I switched to having the image inline as usual, but added a negative top margin equal to its own height (since the image completely fills the cell, it displays underneath the image I want to replace). This worked beautifully and didn't require absolute positioning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So first I style the td with `.css('position', 'relative')`

Check out [WC3 CSS 2.1 Specification : Visual formatting model : 'position' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position):

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group,
>   table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group,
>   table-column, **table-cell**, and table-caption elements **is undefined.**

A common workaround is to wrap a `div` with `position:relative` around everything inside the `td`.

Are you sure you need to be using tables for this?

Comment: Thank you. I'm injecting elements into a page that I have no real control over. It's a corporate intranet built on a large content management system. It won't do what we need but we can get a script tag in so I'm modifying the page with jQuery. Wholesale rewriting would be a waste of time, I just have to work with what is already there and the place I'm inserting content is a table.